# GETDATE() evaluated once per row or once per query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a statement like

```
INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT columns, GETDATE() 
FROM source_table JOIN other tables...
```

Normally it seems like `GETDATE()` is evaluated once for the whole result set and all rows in `target_table` have the same date value.

Is this a guarantee, or are there edge cases where `GETDATE()` could return different values for different rows?

Obviously I could assign `GETDATE()` to a variable to avoid issues -- my question is whether this is strictly necessary or not.

Comment: The answer is given in the comments, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078202/when-using-getdate-in-many-places-is-it-better-to-use-a-variable#comment16223903_12078717

Comment: Thanks.  The answer is mentioned in the accepted answer, even though my question is worded slightly different.  (Better to use vs. MUST use)

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is wrong. The comment is correct. `getdate` is a runtime constant. It is not evaluated per row, but it is evaluated per appearance in the query.